# How can I add Linux source code global variable?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, global-variables, extern

I face a situation where I need to declare a global variable so every file of Linux source code can reference it. As much as I know, Linux is a Monolithic kernel, so this can be done. So I add the global variable to the init/main.c file. However, when I use `extern ..` in other files, the compiler says `undefined reference`. Any help?

#### Update

The more file can access, the better. To be more concrete, I'm tracing the execution times of certain function, so I define a global variable, everytime the function executes, I'll add one. This is the most straightforward way to meet my demand.

Comment: You'll need to add a lot more details on what this variable is intended to do, etc.   Are you expecting to be able to access it from drivers?   Will the variable be updated over time, or is it just some sort of configuration etc.   Depending on what you're doing there will almost certainly be a better solution than using a global variable.   Included the linux-kernel tag, so someone who is an expert can better guide you.

Comment: Your needs will probably be better served by using [kernel tracing](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/events.txt). Maybe create a tracepoint, and use it with perf?